# emacs tramp/CyberArk detailed walkthrough

Tags: tramp, ssh

Edit: Solved...

I'm using emacs 26.2, tramp 2.5.0, on OSX High Sierra 10.13.6...

The server login requires:

1. A normal password
2. A passcode from a phone call
3. The user has to specify a reason for the login

A successful login on a normal terminal looks like this:

```
$ ssh username@target-username@hostname@psmpprod.corp.company-name.com
Enter your Windows domain password:
RADIUS challenge: authfactor.call.prompt Enter '0' to abort.
You are required to specify a reason for this operation:
bla bla bla bla bla
```

#### Connection string:

First, in formatting the ssh string for tramp, I found that I couldn't use the `-l` argument in the ssh call. Found that I would get:

```
$ ssh -l username@target-username -e none hostname@psmpprod.corp.company-name.com

Enter your Windows domain password:
RADIUS challenge: authfactor.call.prompt Enter '0' to abort.
Failed to obtain account. Error: [010E Retrieve target account [__ADBRIDGE_TARGET_USER_TOKEN__] with address [target-username] failed. Error: [076E Password object was not found (Diagnostic Info: 5). Please check that there is a password object that answers your query in the Vault and that both the PSM SSH Proxy and the Vault user have the appropriate permissions needed in order to use the password.]] (Diagnostic Info: 1)
```

But, when you format as one string as at the beginning of the post, it works. So the correct thing to do in `init.el` to define a method `psmx` which would work as `/psmx:target-username@target-hostname` was as follows:

```
(add-to-list 'tramp-methods
             '("psmx"
               (tramp-login-program "ssh")
               (tramp-login-args
                (("-p" "%p")
                 ("%c")
         ("-e" "none")
                 ("username@%u@%h@psmpprod.corp.company-name.com")))
               (tramp-async-args
                (("-q")))
               (tramp-remote-shell "/bin/sh")
               (tramp-remote-shell-login
                ("-l"))
               (tramp-remote-shell-args
                ("-c"))))
```

#### Multi-hop error

Then, in tramp debug log I observed an error related to multi-hops.

```
Host name ‘hostname’ does not match ‘\`\(127\.0\.0\.1\|::1\|[myhostname]\|localhost6?\)\'’
```

I crudely solved it by commenting out the following lines in `tramp.el`:

```
(unless
  (member
   '("%h") (tramp-get-method-parameter item 'tramp-login-args))
...
(tramp-user-error
  vec "Host name `%s' does not match `%s'" host previous-host))
```

#### Parsing strings

Then, so that tramp could read the authfactor prompt and reason for operation, I modified `tramp-password-prompt-regexp` to include `authfactor.call.prompt` and `operation`.

I found out that there were some weird characters in the prompt asking for reason for operation. Wouldn't work unless I put all these junk regex character sets in below:

```
(setq
 tramp-password-prompt-regexp
 (concat
  "^[[:space:][:ascii:][:nonascii:][:cntrl:]]*.*"
  (regexp-opt
   '("passphrase" "Passphrase"
     "password" "Password"
     "authfactor.call.prompt"
     "operation") t)
  ".*[[:space:][:ascii:][:nonascii:][:cntrl:]]*"))
```

This worked, I was prompted for the second authentication step, and the reason for operation, and everything worked out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using TRAMP through CyberArk Privileged Session Manager](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/55814/using-tramp-through-cyberark-privileged-session-manager)

Comment: It's the same problem, I just can't get the solution there to work, don't know why

Comment: That's not a reason to duplicate the question. Instead, add a comment to the original question or one of its answers.

Comment: won't let me, I don't have enough reputation

Comment: Then wait till you do, please.